# Fitting Rectangles

Tags: geometry, packing-problem, rectangles

I have a quantity of small rectangles I need to fit in a larger rectangle frame.  I need an equation to figure out what is the maximum size I can make the small rectangles before they are all too big to fit in the rectangle frame.  I know the quantity of small rectangles and the dimension of the larger rectangle.  The small rectangles will need to stay in ratio (2 by 3).  Can any one help?

Kind regards, Jimmy.

Comment: Why don't you tell us the quantity of small rectangles and the dimension of the larger frame? That way,  we can help solve the specific problem (which might be easy) rather than the general one (which might be quite difficult).